# MVC Login form in all page i want using PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, partial-views

i'm new in this world, so if I say bad things, psl tell me.
I'm trying to run a simple partial login that I can call on any page I want
i'm not using a /shared/_loginPartial because i didn't found something who can explain me how to do it.
I'm using a simple controller and i just recall it with $(#).load("Page url");
Can someone explain me how to do or help me find some video or page ?!

AccountController.cs

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult LoginPartial()
{
   return PartialView();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> LoginPartial(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

    ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Inpu.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return PartialView();
                }
            }

    return PartialView();


}
```

Ex. Index.cshtml

```
<div id="partialZone">
</div>

<script>
      $('#partialZone').load("/Account/LoginPartial");
</script>
```

thanks in advance for the reply.
Please don't be mean, I'm new and learning now